# simpleKml: Adding polygons with multiple innerboundaries (works for Google Earth, not with Google Maps for Android)

Tags: polygon, google-maps, bathymetry, simplekml

This question is about simpleKml used to create bathymetric maps: On how to write the code to provide multiple inner boundaries for a polygon. And: To organize the kml with multiple `innerBoundaryIs` tags with a single `LinearRing` inside, not a single `innerBoundaryIs` with multiple `LinearRing`. Because Google Maps does not handle the latter at all.

I am trying to create klm file for a bathymetric map with help of simpleKml. The resulting kml-file to be used with Google Maps for Android (using the Android SDK utility library). Post-processing the kml-file in Android when displaying the file is not desired.

I am almost there, but I struggle to add "isobaths" (polygons filled with colors). Google Earth is very forgiving, it adds the filled polygons in the correct order almost no matter how I arrange the kml-file. Google Maps is not forgiving at all. For the polygons to display correctly, I must use a combination of `outerBoundaryIs` and `innerBoundaryIs` for each color range (cut out the inner to fit the next depth color). If polygons do not have their inner part not cut out to fit the next level color then Google Maps for Android cannot present the kml in an orderly manner at all (filled polygons appear in random order each time the KML is loaded).

How to use `innerBoundaryIs` I have figured out. But I have one final problem: I need to use multiple inner boundaries (because that's rather common for water bottom contours). I have arranged it by adding the inner boundaries to an array and applying the inner boundaries at the end when all "inner polygons" have been determined. But the resulting KML structure from simpleKml comes out in a way that Google Maps does not handle well at all: In this sample that does not work well with Android Google Maps I have two inner boundaries from range 0 to 1, and simpleKml arranges them as two linear rings within the `innerBoundaryIs` tag:

[image]

And while the result works perfectly in Google Earth, in Google Maps this does not work very good. What does work in Google Maps is using multiple `innerBoundaryIs` rather than two `LinearRing` within a single `innerBoundaryIs`. Like this:

[image]

But I do not get how to make simpleKml add multiple inner boundaries for a given polygon like the above. Maybe I have not looked thoroughly enough into the documentation to find the answer. I did observe I should add a list of inner boundaries to get multiple of them. In the code below, I use an array, but it does not matter if I declare it as a list instead of an array.
After determining that I have one or multiple polygons fitting inside the current polygon, I add these to the array, and at the end I declare the `innerBoundaryIs` as this array.

```
for polygon in range(len(polyOuterName)):
innerBoundaries = []
thisDepth = float(isobath[polygon].name)
thisIsobath = polyOuterPolygon[polygon]
print("")
print("comparing " + str(thisDepth))
for polygonInner in range(len(polyOuterName)):
    innerDepth = float(isobath[polygonInner].name)
    if innerDepth <= thisDepth:
        continue
    if innerDepth > thisDepth +1:
        break
    print("candidate " + str(innerDepth))
    if thisIsobath.contains(polyOuterPolygon[polygonInner]):
        print("candidate has inner polygon")
        innerBoundaries.append(list(polyOuterPolygon[polygonInner].exterior.coords))
    else:
        print("no inner polygon")
if len(innerBoundaries) > 0:
    isobath[polygon].innerboundaryis = innerBoundaries
```

I have also tried to add `innerBoundaryIs` multiple times (one polygon each), but then I always get only one inner boundary (the last one added).

So: I need simpleKml to provide multiple `innerBoundaryIs` tags per polygon instead of multiple `LinearRing` inside a single `innerBoundaryis`. Anyone with ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: By this https://issues.qgis.org/issues/5357 there is a bug in SimpleKML but by the specification https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference I am not sure because it can be interpreted in either way. If "a" means "one" in here  `[innerBoundaryIs] Contains a <LinearRing> element. A Polygon can contain multiple <innerBoundaryIs> elements, which create multiple cut-outs inside the Polygon.` then SimpleKML does it wrong. Write mail and ask and create a bug report if bug is confirmed.

Comment: Thanks. I posted an issue with simplekml here:
https://github.com/eisoldt/simplekml/issues/13

Comment: Seems the working sample I used to compare only had inner boundaries of the identical depth. After "hand coding" the KML to get multiple innerBoundariesIs with a single LinearRing inside I get the exact same behaviour in Google Maps (Android). So I posted a new issue on the Android Maps Utils (this post illustrates the problem well): https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/1132

Comment: I am not sure about KML but in general GIS context that kind of nested holes are not valid. A polygon can have many holes but the holes must not overlap. You must model your data in some other way. For example each depth range as an own polygon with one outer and one outer ring should work.